# jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I know somewhere is answer but i search everywhere.

I have json-server with large data http://localhost:3004/kody

Data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "something",
    "postCode": "something"
  },
  {
    "name": "something",
    "postCode": "something"
}
]
```

now i want to do something like:

when i search in first input by name it display name and postCode in one line: name: something (postCode: something)

And when i click it populate first input with postCode and 2nd input with name.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Hey Lukasz, how is this related to WordPress? And can you please post your jQuery code that isn't working? Is this more of generic JS question? Than you might be better off on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello. Sorry it isnt related to wordpress.